# HTML email paragraf formating not working <del>

Tags: html, powershell, outlook

I have a PowerShell script that send email messages formatted as HTML.

The problem is: when I use a `<del>` HTML tag the paragraph in the email body has a vertical line in front of it - like this:

[image: email message in Outlook]

```bsh
$EmailParam = @{
    From = $From
    To = $To
    Body = 'Some <del>information</del> in email body'
    BodyAsHtml = $true
    Subject = 'test html'
    SmtpServer = $MailServer
}

Send-MailMessage @EmailParam
```

is there any way to use the `<del>` tag without that vertical line appearing?

Comment: Does it make a difference if you explicitly wrap the entire sentence in a paragraph block? `Body = '<p>Some <del>information</del> in email body</p>'`

Comment: almoust the same - just a little bit different formating:

https://i.imgur.com/M4RSqWQ.png